# MySQL create table and alter (add) table query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with sql queries. I have to change my create query to alter table query so that it works the same. My create query is:

```
CREATE TABLE zlecenie (
  ID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ID_ZLECENIA_PODSTAWOWEGO bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `FK_zlecenie_zlecenie_idx` (`ID_ZLECENIA_PODSTAWOWEGO`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_zlecenie_zlecenie` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_ZLECENIA_PODSTAWOWEGO`) REFERENCES `zlecenie` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

My alter (add) table is:

```
ALTER TABLE digitalizacja_choszczno.zlecenie
  ADD COLUMN ID_ZLECENIA_PODSTAWOWEGO BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_ZLECENIA_PODSTAWOWEGO FOREIGN KEY (ID_ZLECENIA_PODSTAWOWEGO) REFERENCES digitalizacja_choszczno.zlecenie (ID) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

But effect is not the same. How can I solved that?

Comment: The real question is what state does the schema start in? `SHOW CREATE TABLE` helps with that.

Comment: What happened to `KEY ``FK_zlecenie_zlecenie_idx`` (``ID_ZLECENIA_PODSTAWOWEGO``)` in your alter-statement?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with:

```
ALTER TABLE digitalizacja_choszczno.zlecenie ADD COLUMN ID_ZLECENIA_PODSTAWOWEGO BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL AFTER CZY_USUNIETY, ADD KEY `FK_zlecenie_zlecenie_idx` (`ID_ZLECENIA_PODSTAWOWEGO`), ADD  CONSTRAINT `FK_zlecenie_zlecenie` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_ZLECENIA_PODSTAWOWEGO`) REFERENCES `zlecenie` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Thanks for helps!